# Single console for multiple apps each served under same domain

Tags: angular, architecture, httpserver

I am trying to figure out the architecture for following kind of requirement.
There are many different angular2 apps each being developed by different teams. I want them to be available under a common console available at **somedomain.com**  . Something like this.
[image: common console]

On opening each app should be served from the same domain like this

```
app1 -> somedomain.com/app1
app2 -> somedomain.com/app2
```

and like wise,  so that user feels these are services of a common application.
Something of this sort happens in aws console.

I also want each team to be able to maintain their own repository and maintain independent CI/CD pipeline.

What I have tried is something like this
[image: Current Design]

All the angular apps is placed on the same box where the http server is.
And I have modified their base tag like this

```
app1 : <base href="/app1/"/>
app2 : <base href="/app2/"/>
```

This solves the problem of serving from the common domain. But their deployment is  tightly coupled with server box as they all share a common box.

Is there an architecture or pattern to tackle this kind of problem? I want to design something which can be scaled for n number of apps in addition to those being managed and developed by independent teams.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your angular apps to a AWS S3 bucket with /app1 & /app2 directories inside which hosts the angular apps. You can keep a index.html for app selection page. Then using AWS CloudFront infront of S3 buckets with a domain mapping of somedomain.com, you can make them available accordingly.

Apart from that, you can also connect to the backend server through CloudFront avoiding CORs challenges.

Comment: S3 is good for serving static websites. I dont think it fits the my current use case

Comment: When you design the architecture, you can move your AngularJS part and static content to S3 (Even the html), unless you have server rendering